# Airflow ExternalTaskSensor not Launch

Tags: airflow

I have 2 dags, when second dag should be launched when all tasks of dag 1 finish.

I have this code:

```
download_exchange_rate_dag_name = 'daily-currency-exchange-rate-v2'

start_date = datetime.datetime(2023, 11, 1, 0, 0, 0)

dag = DAG(download_exchange_rate_dag_name,
          schedule_interval="@daily",
          concurrency=2,
          max_active_runs=1,
          start_date=start_date,
          catchup=True,
          default_args={"depends_on_past": True},
          on_failure_callback=on_failure_callback,
          tags=['exchange-rate-dags'])

dag_dbt = DAG(
        "daily-currency-exchange-rate-dbt-job",
        schedule_interval="@once",
        concurrency=2,
        max_active_runs=1,
        start_date=start_date,
        default_args={"depends_on_past": False},
        tags=['exchange-rate-dags']
)

currencies = config.get("EXCHANGE_RATES_CURRENCY_LIST").split(",")

factory = ExchangeRateFactory(config=ConfigImp(), repository=repository)

currencies_nodes = []

for currency in currencies:
    currencies_nodes.append(factory.download_api_data_pipeline(currency=currency, dag=dag, start_date=start_date))

wait_for_download = ExternalTaskSensor(
    task_id='wait_for_currency_download',
    external_dag_id=download_exchange_rate_dag_name,
    external_task_id=None,
    poke_interval=60,
    dag=dag_dbt
)

wait_for_download >> factory.run_dbt_job(task_id="exchange-rates-dbt-job", job_id="EXCHANGE_RATES_DBT_JOB_ID", dag=dag_dbt)
```

but when dag 1 finishes the second one is not executed.

any idea what could be happening?